# dictionary math Python

Tags: dictionary, math, python-3.6

i have a dictionary with several values allocated to 1 key.
How can i calculate the mean of the values allocated to a specific key?

e.g.
dict:{'name' = 1,2,3,3,1}-->  mean = 2

```
rows = (("name", 0.4),
        ("name", "0.3"),
        ("name", "0.9"),
        ("name", "1.2"),
        ("name", "1.1"))

data = {} # dictionary with several values
for row in rows:
data.setdefault(row[0],[]).append(row[1])
print(data)

for x in data.values():
# calculate mean(x)
```

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the mean without Python? Just do the same in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools.groupby`:

```py
import itertools  #groupby
import operator   #itemgetter

rows = (("alice", "0.4"),
        ("alice", "0.3"),
        ("bob", "0.9"),
        ("charlie", "1.2"),
        ("charlie", "1.1"))

grouped = itertools.groupby([(label, float(value)) for (label, value) in sorted(rows)], operator.itemgetter(0))
# [('alice', [("alice", 0.4), ("alice", 0.3)]),
#  ('bob', [("bob", 0.9)]),
#  ('charlie', [("charlie", 1.2), ("charlie", 1.1)])]

def average(g):
  l = [value for label,value in g]
  return sum(l) / len(l)

means = [(label, average(g)) for (label, g) in grouped]
# [('alice', 0.35), ('bob', 0.9), ('charlie', 1.15)]
```

Explanation: first we group by name. This is accomplished by sorting the list and then calling groupby with the key `operator.itemgetter(0)`, which is equivalent to `lambda t: t[0]`. Note that sorting sorts in lexicographical order; which in particular, sorts by names, because the names come first in the pairs.

Then we define an `average` function to calculates the average value in each group, and we apply it to each group using a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Stef, it took a bit of time to understand how it works...:)
Does it also  work with 2 values?
'Alice', 1, 0.4
'Alice', 3, 0.3
'Alice',2, 0.5
Grouped by Name...
Sorted by  1st value
2nd value used for calculations...

Result:
Alice, [0.4, 0.5, 0.3]

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I have a questions to stefs solution. I took the code and ran it with Python 3.7, without issues. Then i ran the script with Python 3.6, the calulation were aborted with errors.

Answer (score -1):

```
sum(map(float, x))/len(x)
```

Or consider a library like `numpy` which has a `numpy.mean()` method

Comment: That´s the type error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'map' and 'int'

Comment: I ran the code you provided with the line above added, and it worked. Sounds like you're missing the closing parenthesis for the `sum` function, which should appear before the `/`